# Powershell List all tables on Azure Storage

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to automate a query from tables on various `Azure` Storages.
The tables are automatically generated with a different name every week

I am looking for a way to automatically generate a list of the tables available on a given storage and then I can use the `foreach()` function to query each table.

I've seen a few bits of scripts here and there but cannot get something effective
for example:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://MyAccountName.table.core.windows.net/Tables/'
[xml]$tables = $response.Content
$tableNames = $tables.feed.entry.content.properties.TableName
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using REST API instead of fetching tables list using Azure PowerShell Cmdlets?

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the list of tables in your storage account you can use Azure PowerShell Cmdlets. There's absolutely no need to do it via consuming REST API. The Cmdlet you would want to use is [`Get-AzureStorageTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603686.aspx).

Here's a sample code:

```
$StorageAccountName = "your storage account name"
$StorageAccountKey = "your storage account key"
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
Get-AzureStorageTable -Context $ctx
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I only saw the email notification regarding your posts.
I thank you for your answers

Comment: Use `New-AzStorageContext` for Az Powershell